# Robots.txt - Disallow all pages but allow all subdir

Tags: robots.txt, subdirectory

somebody can say to me how to write robots.txt file. I need to disallow all pages of a directory but I need to allow access to all relative subdirectories.
You must know that I don't know pages and subdirectories name... they are create automatically.

for example:

Disallow: /dir1/dir2/all-pages.html

Allow: /dir1/dir2/all-subdirectories/

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Allow: /dir1/dir2/*/
Disallow: /dir1/dir2/
```

That should work for Google and Bing. Whether it works for other crawlers is an open question, as there's no universal standard for how `Allow` and `Disallow` work together. But putting the `Allow` first will give you the best chance of it working, because many crawlers use the "first matched rule". So they'll see the `Allow` and continue.